# Seed production database with data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, deployment

I have some data which needs to be inserted to DB after creation. Like system user account, email credentials, supported language codes, etc...

Is it better to put insertion of this data in the Seed method of Entity framework, or to put it in the Sql script and run that script on production after Db is created?

Comment: Does it matter? This is a one time thing right? All that matters is that the data is in the database at the end of deployment. I would do it with a sql script but that is my preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd argue you just be consistent with how you plan to manage migrations after the system is live.  If you're going to use all the built in migration tooling that comes with EF, use the Seed method.  If you're going to write scripts for migrations, then write a script.  The more consistent it is, the easier it will be to figure out why you made the choices you did later on when someone wants to know.